# Why does FileObserver only work in /sdcard/data/[package_name]?

Tags: android, fileobserver

I am trying to monitor all files operations(create, read, write, modify, delete) in ‘/sdcard’ directory. It seems the class FileObserver could do the job from the documentation”https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html”. Iimplement onEvent method like this,

```
 @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, @Nullable String path) {
        Log.d("sdevent",""+event);
        switch(event) {
            case FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS:
                Log.d("sdcardlistener", "path:"+ path);
                break;
            case FileObserver.CREATE:
                Log.d("sdcardlistener", "path:"+ path);
                break;
        }
    }
```

But when I try it on my Android studio 3.5.3 using emulator Pixel2(API 28) and my own phone which is Android Q now, I cannot get any event on path ‘/sdcard’ or its subdirectory ,‘/sdcard/DCIM’ for example. The code is like this.

```
SDCardListener listener1=new SDCardListener("/sdcard");
listener1.startWatching();
```

If I change the path to a app-specific one, like ‘/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myfiletest(my app name)/files/apple’, it seems to work for the directory and its fist subdirectory.

```
SDCardListener listener2=new SDCardListener("/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.myfiletest/files/apple");
listener2.startWatching();
```

Since this situation doesn’t match documentation, I want to know where is the problem. And is there a way to monitor all file changes in externel storage if FileObserver not capable to do so.

Comment: did you asked permission for read/write data on storage or sd card?

Comment: Thanks for your reminding! I wrote permissions in the manifest file but didn’t do the runtime permission checking. Now it works fine.

Comment: Are you telling it wirks on Q now too?

Comment: @blackapps 
No, just tried on Q, sadly it did't output any event number. :( Any ideas why?

Comment: On Android Q /sdcard cannot be used anymire nor not app specific directories.